# iOS/iPhone best practice for handling events

Tags: iphone, ios

I am just starting out with iOS programming. I'm currently looking through the [MoveMe](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/MoveMe/Introduction/Intro.html) example and had a question about event handlers.

In the example, they have the `MoveMeView` (subclass of `UIView`) handle events (`touchesBegan:withEvent:`, etc.). It seems like this belongs on a controller though, not the view. Is there a standard way of doing this, or any guidelines on the division of responsibility between a view and a controller?

Answer (score 0):

Touch handling is in the responsibility of the view. Just like you I think it should be on some kind of controller and Apple luckily introduced UIGestureRecognizer in iOS3.2. If you are targeting anything below 3.2 you'll have to stick with the touchesBegan/Moved/Ended methods, or create something for yourself.

For targets after 3.2 please take a look at [UIGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and it's subclasses and read the [Gesture Recognizers](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH6-SW1) chapter in the Event Handling Guide. It's also possible you create your own subclass, if you have touch handling needs not covered by the shipping gesture Recognizers.